# Assign a name to a set of type constraints in F#?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a generic type with some complex type constraints in F#:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type Vec2<'t when 't : equality
              and 't : comparison
              and 't : (static member get_Zero : Unit -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (-) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (*) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (/) : 't * 't -> 't)> =
  {
    X : 't
    Y : 't
  }
```

Now I want to create another generic type that builds on this:

```ml
// Does not work

[<Struct>]
type AABB<'t> =
  {
    Min : Vec2<'t>
    Max : Vec2<'t>
  }
```

This does not work unless I replicate the type constraints:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type AABB<'t when 't : equality
              and 't : comparison
              and 't : (static member get_Zero : Unit -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (-) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (*) : 't * 't -> 't)
              and 't : (static member (/) : 't * 't -> 't)> =
  {
    Min : Vec2<'t>
    Max : Vec2<'t>
  }
```

This gets old fast!

Is there a way to bind the type constraints to a name so that I can reuse them throughout my code?

```ml
// Not real code

constraint IsNumeric 't = 
      't : equality
  and 't : comparison
  and 't : (static member get_Zero : Unit -> 't)
  and 't : (static member (+) : 't * 't -> 't)
  and 't : (static member (-) : 't * 't -> 't)
  and 't : (static member (*) : 't * 't -> 't)
  and 't : (static member (/) : 't * 't -> 't)

[<Struct>]
type Vec2<'t when IsNumeric 't> =
  {
    X : 't
    Y : 't
  }

[<Struct>]
type AABB<'t when IsNumeric 't> =
  {
    Min : Vec2<'t>
    Max : Vec2<'t>
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your use case is, i.e. why you cannot tuck the constraints away with the inline functions that operate on your type, ideally in a separate module? Otherwise a very valid question!

Comment: @kaefer I want to define new types that compose the other types. I suppose passing each record property as a parameter would work. but I think it would be less readable. It also prevents building collections of the composed types, for example.

Answer (score 5):

A reasonable workaround in this case is to create an interface that represents the constraints. This does not automatically work as named constraint, but you can define a helper function that captures the required operations and then pass the interface around (so that you can invoke the operations you want).

Let's say we want just addition and multiplication:

```
type INumericalOps<'T> = 
  abstract Add : 'T * 'T -> 'T
  abstract Mul : 'T * 'T -> 'T

[<Struct>]
type Vec2<'T> =
  { X : 'T
    Y : 'T }

[<Struct>]
type AABB<'T, 'O when 'O :> INumericalOps<'T>> =
  { Min : Vec2<'T>
    Max : Vec2<'T>
    Ops : 'O }
```

Now, the `AABB` type also contains an implementation of the `INumericalOps` interface, which is somewhat shorter than specifying all the constraints. We can create an inline function that captures the implementation of `*` and `+` for any type that supports those:

```
let inline capture () = 
  { new INumericalOps<_> with
    member x.Add(a, b) = a + b
    member x.Mul(a, b) = a * b }
```

When creating a value, the type inference will make sure we get the right implementation of numerical operations:

```
let aabb = 
  { Min = { X = 1.0; Y = 2.0 }
    Max = { X = 1.0; Y = 2.0 }
    Ops = capture() }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nicer from a programming perspective, but I think I see two downsides. 1) dispatch to the interface will be slower because it is at run-time (unless F# compiler is smart enough?) 2) comparison and equality on `AABB` will be broken by the inclusion of a reference type

Comment: Should add, the ability to include extra operations, such as `get_PI` could be a deciding factor in favour of this approach.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is essentially this request https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/641

Short answer, not supported in F# at this stage but I think it would be a great feature to add.

Answer (score 4):

Your example looks like [generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/). This thing will be supported in net6 as [preview feature](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2021/preview-features/preview-features.md). This has advantages over all others approaches: native support in runtime, C# support it (more libs available), no runtime cost (performance is same as with direct call)

Even though there's no support for this in F# yet, it could look like this (not final, syntax may change)

```ml
type IAdditionOperators<'a> =
    static abstract (+) : 'a * 'a -> 'a

type IAdditionIdentity<'a> =
    inherit IAdditionOperators<'a>
    static abstract Zero : 'a

/// This vector type supports addition of 2 generic values
[<Struct>]
type Vector2<'a when 'a : IAdditionIdentity<'a>>(x, y) =
    member val X = x
    member val Y = y
    static member (+) (left, right) =
        Vector<'a>('a.(+)(left.X, right.X), 'a.(+)(left.Y, right.Y))

/// This vector supports all methods from INumber
[<Struct>]
type RichVector2<'a when 'a : INumber<'a>>(x, y) =
    member val X = x
    member val Y = y
    static member (+) (left, right) =
        Vector<'a>('a.(+)(left.X, right.X), 'a.(+)(left.Y, right.Y))
    interface INumber<'a> with
        static member (+) (left, right) =
             RichVector<'a>.(+)(left, right)
        // Requires implementation for +, -, *, /, DivRem,
        // Zero, One, Abs, Max, Min, Sign, Clamp, 
        // Create, CreateSaturating, CreateTruncating, TryCreate,
        // Parse, TryParse
```